# MVC 5 Sharing between Web Application and Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I am in the process of learning ASP.NET MVC 5 (Visual Studio 2015) and have created a basic MVC web application.  When I created the project, I selected "MVC" and "Web API" under "Add folders and core references for:".  I also selected "Individual User Accounts" under authentication.  I created some models, controllers, and views using EF.  Those are working great along with authentication.  I also created a "Web API 2 Controller with actions using Entity Framework" to add API capabilities to one of my models.  Again this works fine.

Now I am trying to get OAuth working with the Web API but ran into problems when requesting the Token...  I don't think the Web Application template comes with that piece.  After much reading, I found some recommendations on Stack Overflow that it is usually better to create a separate project for your Web API.

So my questions are:

I will most likely be deploying the Web API on one server and/or subdomain and the Web Application on another.  If that is the case, they have to be in separate projects anyways, right?

When having two projects, what is the best way to share common components, like models?  In my Web API, should I add a reference to my Web Application and then create the Web API Controller like that or should I copy the code from the model and create a new model in the Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, they need to be separate projects if you are going to deploy them seperately.
2. To handle common items, create a library DLL project and reference that from both the Web API and Web App. It can contain the common components.

Also, if you are using cookies for authentication, you are also going to have to setup CORS to allow the cookie to be shared between two sites with different domains.

Comment: So I would create a new class library project in my solution, create the model, and then in both the Web API and Web Application, add a reference to the project and then build the controller for it?  Can you explain why that is better than just building the model in my Web Application and then referencing it in the Web API?  For authentication, I'm just using the default setup in the templates and the Web App won't need to communicate with the Web API anyways.

Comment: By putting the common code into a separate place, you are essentially decoupling the common code from both the Web API and the Web App. This allows this code to be tested independently of both of those solutions. Plus, it insures that the Web API project will never conflict with the Web App project.